# Selenide sometimes does not fill the form input

Tags: java, selenium, selenide

I have some tests written using the Java Selenide framework. In most cases (25:1) the tests are successful. But sometimes I get a weird error which is caused by sending empty inputs in the form.

I don't understand why it happens. It is not a one form issue. Sometimes it is the login form, sometimes it is another form.

The code is straightforward and looks like this:

```java
public void fillName(String text) 
{
  $(byName("name")).val(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tempering with the element attributes, like value or text, is a bad practice.

Before you you try to click on an element (or type text inside it) using Selenium plugin make sure that the element is clickable.

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, secondsToWait);            
 lastFoundElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
 By.id(elementID)));
 lastFoundElement.sendKeys("Your text to type here");
```

Some elements won't update the text inside them if you try to change or override the Value or Text attribute. The correct way to do so is to call sendKeys and the value you wish to be written in the element.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by tempering? I thing Selenide do this stuff like waiting while element is clickable under the hood .The problem was in my VPS resources. Too much parallel runs.

Comment: @Čamo No, Selenium does NOT wait for element to be clickable under the hood. You need to ask for it. The right way to type text is like in the code sample I gave you.

Comment: I wrote Selenide NOT Selenium.

Comment: @Čamo This question has a tag of Selenium + Java. Change my code so it will fit your needs.

Comment: Your code probably works but this question has also tag Selenide. And it was not the problem. As I say my problem was resources on the server.